# How to handle the NSString starts with "\0"

Tags: objective-c

i have a NSString starts with "\0", then i read it and wants to do some action with this NSString, but i found the length is not 0 and the content is nothing.

```
NSString *str = @"\0afasfsafsda";  // some string read from a file
NSLog(@"%@",str);  //output nothing
NSLog(@"%@", [str length]); //12
```

right now i want to check wheather a NSString is this type, how to do this?

```
if([str isEqualTo:@""] && [str length]==?)
```

Comment: What do you get for `[str characterAtIndex:0]`?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert it output nothing

Comment: Why does a string read from a file begin with a null terminator?

Comment: @jimwan it doesn't output "nothing" it probably outputs a `0`, which is exactly what `\0` means.

Comment: characterAtIndex:0 doesn't give you nothing. It gives you the first character which happens to be the null character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for a `\0` first character like this:

```
NSString *str = @"\0afasfsafsda";

BOOL firstCharIsNull = (str.length > 0 && [str characterAtIndex:0] == 0);

if (firstCharIsNull) {
  NSLog(@"yes");
} else {
  NSLog(@"no");
}
```